# Docusign - embedded signing - redirecting to user profile instead of document

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docusignapi

I am using Docusign's `docusign_esign` gem in a Rails 7 app with great success in local development (localhost:3000).

The issue is when the app gets deployed to the cloud, the signing work flow breaks. Instead of getting redirected to the document to sign after successfully completing the initial SSO step, User gets redirected to their Docusign profile page.

Here's the breakdown of steps:

1. User signs into the rails app
2. User gets redirected to the embedded workflow
3. the first step of which is a sso login
4. then the user *should* get redirected to the document, but the issue is that get forwarded to the user's profile (the settings, etc)

Anyone have any insight into what this could be? Thanks!

[unwanted 302 after successful SSO image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsLZy.png)

---

- Rails 7.0.3.1
- docusign_esign 3.18.0
- ruby 3.0.2

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer.. Was a simple config issue, I was missing the `DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATION_KEY` in the release environment.